# How to allow pam to execute mount

Tags: linux, encryption, mount

I am trying to setup ecryptfs on my Gentoo system, but I am constantly getting to issues with automounting the home folder.

ecryptfs works in the way that there is a password file encrypted with user's password that contains a key to decrypt the home folder. When user login, PAM module use the password provided by user do decrypt the file and obtain the password for filesystem, then it's meant to execute mount command to mount the system.

Running this by hand as root works fine, but I can't get it to work automatically through pam_mount, here is a guide I followed: http://gentoo-en.vfose.ru/wiki/Encrypt_home_directory_with_ecryptfs

Now I am getting this issue:

```
mount.c:72): mount: only root can mount /home/.ecryptfs/petr.bena/.Private on /home/petr.bena
```

I was googling and found that PAM is not allowed to use mount command for security reasons. To be honest, I don't care. I am willing to sacrifice the "security" of my system and allow PAM to do mounts. Because having non-encrypted home folder is significantly higher security issue IMHO.

Also nobody else than me has direct access to this laptop, so having non-root users able to do mounts is OK to me (all non-root users have sudo anyway).

Is there a way to allow PAM to do mount?

UPDATE: I figured out that adding option "user" to fstab allow regular users to mount, now I get this error, though:

```
(mount.c:72): mount: mount(2) failed: No such file or directory
```

Which makes no sense, because the paths are correct. Most likely related to ecryptfs itself

Comment: Does gentoo not implement eCryptFS or encrypted homes correctly? This sounds like it should be a bug report for gentoo, you're just trying to get eCryptFS to work normally?

Comment: I don't think gentoo really implements anything. It just takes the source code and let user compile it and configure by hand. If there is a bug it's either in eCryptFS or in eCryptFS manual.

Comment: In fact, I managed to get ecryptfs working, so problem isn't on their side, what doesn't work is pam automount, so the bug here is probably in pam or its documentation which doesn't really describe the configuration details in a clear way.

Comment: Never tried gentoo, just familiar with Debian U Ubuntu based distros, packages are *supposed* to be tested & *usually* work ok ;-) Have an idea about pam, posted some info

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [pam_ecryptfs man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/pam_ecryptfs.8.html) has some clues, mentions needing entries in files in `/etc/pam.d` and probably need the file `/lib/security/pam_ecryptfs.so` (or in some other location?)

> To  unwrap  a  mount  passphrase  and  automatically  mount  a 
>   private
>          directory on login, add the following lines to
>
> ```
>    /etc/pam.d/common-auth:
>
>               auth    required        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
>
>    /etc/pam.d/common-session:
>
>               session optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
> ```

On Linux Mint, my `/etc/pam.d/common-auth` file has the line:

```
auth    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

and `/etc/pam.d/common-session` has:

```
session optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```

Actually, any files in `/etc/pam.d/` containing "ecrypt" are these:

```
$ grep ecrypt /etc/pam.d/*
/etc/pam.d/common-auth:auth optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/common-password:password optional    pam_ecryptfs.so 
/etc/pam.d/common-session:session   optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive:session    optional    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
```